# Making Input fields like Mail app on OSX

Tags: forms, html, css, input

How can I make input fields like that in the Mail App on OSX.

Here is a screenshot -

[image: Screenshot]

What I want is the ability to group text like it is shown in the image above. So, instead of having several input field (eg. in the case of the mail app - from, to, subject etc), I can do with a single one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the question here, but I'm guessing some clever use of CSS where you place a drop-down menu and an input form within a div styled to look like an input form would work?

Comment: i wanted to know if there is some html5/css3 based library which can allow me to do this....

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt there is :( this shouldn't be too complicated to make with basic CSS3 though.